# Hacer un header dinámico con JS y la barra de scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero hacer un header dinámico que cuando el scroll se mueve un poco se le añada a la clase "position:fixed;" y si vuelve a la altura inicial se le quite....

Os dejo el código que he hecho se que me falta algo pero no se el que, agradecería vuestra ayuda compañeros!!

```js
if(document.window.scrollTop > 0){
            document.querySelector('.header-middle').style.position = 'fixed';
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.header-middle').style.position = 'unset';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Caballoderally yo lo haría de esta manera:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    if(document.window.scrollTop > 0){
        document.getElementsByClassName('header-middle').style.position = 'fixed';
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('header-middle').style.position = 'unset';
    }
};
```

window.onscroll es cada vez que el scroll se mueva que haga lo que haces tu aunque en vez de usar una clase para el header yo le pondría el id y modificaría el `getElementsByClassname` por `document.getElementById(id);`

Comment: Vale muchas gracias eso hare, ya te digo si funciona jeje muchas gracias!!!